# Selecting data not matching query

Tags: sql, date, select, sql-server-2012

I want to select only the data that does not match a query.

Say I have two tables:

*cars:*

```
id         int          PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
make       varchar(255) NOT NULL
model      varchar(255) NOT NULL
pricegroup varchar(1)   NOT NULL
```

---

*rentals:*

```
id         int          PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
sdate      date         NOT NULL
edate      date         NOT NULL
car_id     int          NOT NULL
```

---

**sdate** in rentals is the starting date of the rental - **edate** is the end date.

I want to find all available cars between a specified time period.

This query almost works:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id NOT IN 
  (SELECT car_id FROM rentals WHERE sdate <='2013-04-28' AND edate >='2013-04-30')
```

However, it only works with specific dates. If you enter a period between **2013-04-25** and **2013-05-30** all cars shows up, even though some of them are booked in between that period.

I use MS SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the dates the other way around:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id NOT IN 
  (SELECT car_id FROM rentals WHERE sdate <='2013-04-30' AND edate >='2013-04-28')
```

Also, using `NOT EXISTS` may give you better performance than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM rentals WHERE car_id=cars.id AND edate>=start_date AND sdate<=end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert all date to datetime format with time as 0 (i.e 2013-04-28 00:00:00.000 ).

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT car_id FROM rentals WHERE 
    Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),sdate,106)) as sdate >= Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),'2013-04-28',106)) AND 
    Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),edate,106)) as edate <= Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),'2013-04-30',106)))
```

Comment: Why would that be neccessary?

Comment: If you have date like this i.e 2013-04-28 12:39:12.000. You cant get this date if you use where query like this **where sdate = 2013-04-28**. I faced such problems so i always convert to this format **2013-04-28 00:00:00.000**

Comment: Well, the date inserted in my database is only the date, and no time at all, so that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Hooo k. then you dont have problem. But u can use like this for input **Convert(datetime, '2013-04-30')**

Comment: That was some useful input :)